# ember-simple-auth oauth2 authorizer issue

Tags: authentication, ember.js, oauth

I am trying to set up authorization on an Ember App running on a Node.js server.

I am using the oauth2 Authenticator, which is requesting a token from the server. This is working fine. I am able to provide the app with a token, which it saves in the local-storage.

However, when I make subsequent requests, the authorizer is not adding the token to the header, I have initialized the authorizer using the method described in the documentation (http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/ember-simple-auth-oauth2-api-docs.html):

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    Ember.SimpleAuth.setup(container, application, {
        authorizerFactory: 'authorizer:oauth2-bearer'
    });
  }
});

var App = Ember.Application.create();
```

And I have added an init method to the Authorizer, to log a message to the server when it is initialized, so I know that it is being loaded. The only thing is, the authorize method of the authorizer is never called.

It feels like I am missing a fundamental concept of the library.

I have a users route which I have protected using the AuthenticatedRouteMixin like so:

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function() {
    return this.get('store').find('user');
  }
});
```

Which is fetching the data, fine, and redirects to /login if no token is in the session, but the request headers do not include the token:

```
GET /users HTTP/1.1
Host: *****
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: *****
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36
Referer: *****
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is your REST API served on a different origin than the app is loaded from maybe? Ember.SimpleAuth does not authorizer cross origin requests by default (see here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#cross-origin-authorization)

Comment: Marcos when I add the cross origin authorization to environment config file, my ember app sends OPTIONS request instead of GET. any idea please?

Comment: That's CORS - the browser sends an OPTIONS request first to figure out what the server allows before it sends the actual GET request. You also need to make sure your server supports CORS and responds correctly to these OPTIONS requests.

Comment: thanks marcos you're right, I configured cors on server and seems it works. One little thing that I am facing this issue when wanted to use auth devise authorizer by configuring crossOriginWhitelist, but I actually cannot send the token and email in header under an AuthenticatedRoute, would u know what ma I doing wrong?